# Excel keyboard shortcuts are switched – how do I set them back to their defaults?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a spreadsheet created by someone else. They switched <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the row, and <kbd>Home</kbd> to the start of the worksheet.

Also, I have the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key jumping 30 columns to the right instead of the next column.

How do I set these back to the defaults? It has now affected any Excel document I create.

Comment: Does it affect any other Excel document you create even after you close the "problematic" file?

Comment: Yes - all of my Excel documents now work this way.  They did not do this until I started using the new file.

Comment: Was their a macro in the file from these guys?

Comment: No - don't see a macro in the original.

Comment: One of your keyboard keys might be "stuck" - click several time on all `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `Shift` keys and see if it resolves the problem. (you would also notice strange behavior on other applications as well in such a case)